# Trying to produce automated daily call reports through RingCentral either by webscraping or by emailing the .csv export

Tags: javascript, python, email, csv, ringcentral

Since RingCentral (VOIP) phone provider does not provide any call statistic reporting, I am looking for an alternative.

I want to automate this as much as possible, and avoid having to go to the website everyday, send the report through email, open the email import the `.csv` into Excel and run the script.

I have believe I have two options here (correct me if you know of more):

1. Webscrape from Ringcentral.com
2. Create an email address to send automatic reports to daily. I then would probably use Python to access this `.csv` file, apply macro, and send results to another email.

I am looking for guidance on the best way to approach this problem. If someone would like to see how the data is embedded in the website I can provide the source code. It is JavaScript, which I am not familiar with.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks, 
J

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RingCentral REST API to retrieve Call Log Records in JSON format. This is available directly from the API and via the SDKs which includes both Python and JavaScript.

- API Guide: https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-docs/index.html##GetCallLog.html
- SDKs: https://github.com/ringcentral

As a note, the RingCentral Online Account Portal does provide some call reporting now, so if that works for you, there would be no development necessary.